# How to get the raw row content in Cassandra 3.3

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I am using Cassandra 3.3 and CQL to create the following table

```
CREATE TABLE collected_data ( 
    collection_hour int,
    source_id int, 
    entity_id int, 
    measurement text, 
    value text, 
    primary key((collection_hour),source_id,entity_id,measurement)  
);
```

After inserting a bunch of values into this table I wish to see how **each row** is really stored in Cassandra. For that I have seen that folks were using cassandra-cli (list command), but that is not available anymore in 3.3 ( post 3.0 )

Is there a way I can use to query cassandra to see how each row is really stored ? I am looking for some tool or any way to do this from CQL ...

Thank you

PS: in cassandra CLI one would use the the "list command" and get an output similar to the following (different table ofcourse):

```
RowKey: 1
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=field2, value=00000002, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=field3, value=00000003, timestamp=1374546754299000)

RowKey: 4
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=field2, value=00000005, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=field3, value=00000006, timestamp=1374546757815000)
```

Comment: You can use Datastax DevCenter for that

Comment: I tried to do that with devcenter , but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do that. DevCenter is able to print the table content in in a .... well .. table format --- X rows x Y columns and this is not what I am looking for. I need the raw format in which is stored in Cassandra. I need this to make sure I understood correctly how the data is stored ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage engine has been rewritten since Cassandra 3.0 so the on-disk layout has changed completely.

There is no official documentation on this subject but you can look at several places in the source code to have a big picture of how data are laid on disk

`UnfilteredSerializer`: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.java#L29-L71

`Cell` storage: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Cell.java#L145-L163

`ClusteringPrefix`: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/ClusteringPrefix.java#L33-L45

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It would seem that indeed there have been significant changes on how the data is stored in 3.0+ some of that is detailed in http://www.datastax.com/2015/12/storage-engine-30. Thanks